# Express js - MVC how to render parts

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have some experience in PHP's codeignter framework, and in there I could include views depending on the route, for example "/about" route:
header.html about.html footer.html

How can I do the same in express, because view can be rendered once,
should I do conditionals inside the template and pass an object to combine or
is there a better way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: You can use template inheritance with jade for instance. Check the documentation.

Comment: for jade yes but I prefer ejs though

Comment: ejs has deprecated the concept of 'layout'. I used [swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) for a while, but then switched to using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) for client-side MVC framework.